# Can't place icons in the certain places in windows desktop screen

Tags: windows-10

I am unable to place desktop icons in the desired place which I need to place. When I drag the icon to the certain place, it automatically goes to the left side of the windows screen. Any fix please?

When I drag the icon to the certain place, it automatically goes to the left side of the windows screen. Any fix please?
OS: Windows 10
Laptop: DELL